# How to guarantee file removing after script stopped working?

Tags: python, process, pid

I have a script running by crontab every hour and interacts with API (database sync). Usually it take one hour or so, and I check for the next run if this process still in the memory or not:

```
#/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys

pid = str(os.getpid())
pidfile = "/tmp/mydaemon.pid"

if os.path.isfile(pidfile):
    print "%s already exists, exiting" % pidfile
    sys.exit()
file(pidfile, 'w').write(pid)
try:
    # Do some actual work here
finally:
    os.unlink(pidfile)
```

BUT after some time script stopped working, when I look at the "ps aux | grep python", I don't see this script as the process, but I do see file on the place.
And when I run script manually, I see information printed iteratively on the screen, but after some time I see the word "Terminated", script exited and file still on the place.

How to guarantee 100% the file removed after the script stopped working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can use `atextit` module functionality, but in your case (unexpected termination) it also may not work.

Maybe use of `mkstemp` (specifying required program suffix/refix) within `with` statement may work: it will create unique pidfile in `/tmp` and clear it, when `with` block completes or terminates.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your script is terminated unexpectedly, most probably due to too high memory usage. It's not guaranteed that `finally` will be executed on unexpected program termination. So, first of all I suggest you to find the cause of the unexpected termination an fix it.

Actually there is no 100% way to guarantee that the file will be removed. However, there are a few workarounds for handling dangling pid files.

Place your pid files on the `/var/run` volume, so they will be removed on unexpected system restart.

Check wether the process with such pid is still running on each script execution:

```
import os

def is_alive(pid):
    try:
        os.kill(pid, 0)  # do nothing but throws an exception 
        return True
    except OSError:
        return False

# and add this to your code:
if os.path.isfile(pidfile):
    with open(pidfile) as f:
        if is_alive(f.read()):
            sys.exit()
```

Again, provided code is not 100% safe because of possible pid collisions. You can make the verification of running process more sophisticated by adding parsing of `ps` command output. Try to find a line with the desired pid value and check wether it looks similar to your crontab entry.